# Simultaneous calls to Google Sheets API

Tags: google-sheets-api

I'm developing an application in which race conditions could occur when calling the Google Sheets API. This can happen due to multiple separate users executing the same use case with significantly different parameters. All requests from these users are handled separately and asynchronously.

For simplicity's sake I'll refer to these calls as call A and call B. Both being completely different and asynchronous requests. The values written in both calls will be completely different, hence the output in the read calls will return completely different values.

Normal situation:

1. Write call A
2. Read call A
3. Write call B
4. Read call B

Simultaneous calls:

1. Write call A
2. Write call B
3. Read call A (this now unintentionally fetches the result written by call B)
4. Read call B

When both actions are executed simultaneously a condition can occur that the write of call B could race the read of call A. This results in malformed output in the read of call A as the parameters of B are used.

Obviously I should improve the applications design by using a queue mechanism, but I'm hoping multiple users have bumped into this problem and that the API has a solution to this issue.

I've been nosing around in the API documentation and couldn't find support for certain cases other than having multiple duplicate sheets and randomising the IDs within my application.